# Female rat suddenly having vaginal discharge

Tags: health, rat

[image][image]

Clover is almost a year old now and she randomly gained weight and feels heavier, she also is getting a lot of mucus over her “lady parts”. I just recently adopted a male rat from a coworker so I don’t know if she could have possibly gotten out and is now pregnant or if it’s something like pyometra or even something else. I read something where if it was an infection she would have a funky smell down there but she doesn’t.

Comment: If you want to know for sure and have the resources for it, visit a vet.

Comment: Did you ever figure it out ? My rat is having the same problem